# Unity rotation of a sphere for 360° image wiewer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, limit

I've been looking for a solution for long time but nothing worked...
I'm using unity, I got a sphere an my camera inside of this one to make a 360° image wiewer (I've my picture inside of the shpere).
I make it rotate with the keybord arrows but I want to stop the vertical rotation beetwin two values.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TransformFonctions : MonoBehaviour {

// Initialisation do nothing
void Start () {

}

//Two speeds of rotation, right and left faster than up and down
public float moveSpeed = 10f;
public float turnSpeed = 50f;
public float maxUp = 7f;
public float maxDown = -22f;

//Four methods in the update : turn right, left, up and down
// up and down are in a range

void Update (){

    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow)) {

        if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x <= maxUp) {

            transform.Rotate (Vector3.right * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);


    if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow)) {

        if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.x >= maxDown) {

            transform.Rotate (Vector3.left * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);   
        }
    }

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, turnSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
}
```

This code doesn't work but I don't know why...
May someone help me? =)